# Is there a way to give equal weighing to two row values in MySQL when ordering by FIELD?

Tags: mysql

```
ORDER BY FIELD(store.location, "MP12221", "MP62112","MP15314") ASC, distance ASC
```

I have this query that uses FIELD to sort the location and then sort by distance since I want these three to be last regardless of the distance from the user, but I want equal weighing for store MP12221 and MP62112. How can you do that? Because in my understanding using this query will make sure that MP12221 is always before MP62112.

I need all the stored to be sorted by distance except the three and then have MP12221 and MP62112 to be sorted by distance and then have MP15314 come last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting via a `CASE` expression might more sense here:

```sql
ORDER BY
    CASE store.location
        WHEN 'MP12221' THEN 1
        WHEN 'MP62112' THEN 1
        WHEN 'MP15314' THEN 2
        ELSE 3 END,
    distance
```